# How to make a Python script that does a task in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, vba

When I run this code in QGIS Python console it works fine, but I want want to run it from an external Python script.

What I want the script to do is:
1- Open QGIS
2- Run this code
3- Close QGIS

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

mapinstance = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

uri =  "file:///C:/Users/Home/Desktop//sample.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "Long", "Lat") 

vlayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri,"sample","delimitedtext")
mapinstance.addMapLayer(vlayer)

uri="C:/Users/Home/Desktop/Style.qml"
vlayer.loadNamedStyle(uri)


vlayer.selectAll()
qgis.utils.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
vlayer.invertSelection ()

qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage('/Users/HOME/Desktop/capture.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

You will want to run this as a standalone application. The reference for this can be found in the appropritate [pyqgis cookbook section](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications).

You need to run setup code at the beginning and cleanup code at the end.

```
# ...
# [ Your imports here ]
# ...

# supply path to where is your qgis installed
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis/installation", True)

# load providers
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# ...
# [ Your code here ]
# ...

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()

canvas.saveAsImage('/Users/HOME/Desktop/capture.png')

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Comment: when I try to run the .py script with the OSGeo4W Shell but nothing happens.
when I try to open it with the standalone python installation, it give me an error "ImportError: No module named sip"

Comment: What do you mean by "noting happens"? The OSGeo4W python is surely the right thing to use, as that's what QGIS builds upon.

Comment: It doesn't accept this line of the code 
"qgis.utils.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()"
and also, how can I make the OSGEO4W the default python interpreter. Thank you.

Comment: `iface` is not available. So instead you will have to use some custom code to bring things up and running... Updating the example...